# kubernetes share non-empty volume

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, volume

In my application with docker-compose I have 2 container, 1 nginx and 1 python script crontab that update some files in nginx/html folder.
With docker-compose when I declare

```
volumes:
    - shared-volume:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/xxx:ro
```

the initial files in the nginx images are copied to the shared volume.

Now I'm trying to move the application to k8s, but when I use shared volume I see that initial files in nginx/html are missing.

So the question is, is it possible to copy initial files from my nginx images to the shared volume? How?

____________________________EDIT______________________________________

To clarify, I'm new to k8s, With VM we usually run script that update an nginx assets folder. With docker-compose I use something like this:

```html
version: '3.7'
services:
  site-web:
    build: .
    image: "site-home:1.0.0"
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - v_site-home:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/:ro
  site-cron:
    build: ./cronScript
    image: "site-home-cron:1.0.0"
    volumes:
    - v_site-home:/app/my-assets
volumes:
  v_site-home:
    name: v_site-home
```

Now I'm starting to write a deployment (with persistent volume? Because as I understand even if there is a persistent volume a stateful set is not useful in this case) to convert my docker-compose to k8s. Actually we cannot use any public cloud for security policy (data must be in our country and now there's no big company with this option). So the idea is to run vanilla k8s in multiple bare metal server and start migration with very simple application like this. I tried with the 2 docker, replica:1 and an empty volume in a single pod. In this case I see that initially the application has the nginx folder empty, and I need to wait the crontab update to see my results. So this is the first problem.

Now I read your answer and obviously I've other doubts. Is it better to split the pod, so 1 pod for container? A deployment with persistent volume is the way? In this case, I've the old problem, how to see initial nginx assets files? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Show us the real yaml file. I would guess you deploy with seperate pods. Be notes: you can deploy both nginx and python application into one pod with two containers.

Comment: see my answer! thanks

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question, but just to clarify your own question. You need update your original question directly.

Answer (score 2):

This generally requires an initContainer which runs cp. it’s not a great solution but it gets the job done.

Comment: Nonono. The poster just doesn't mention clearly how to set the pod with several containers, It will be very simple to do `volumeMount`. I guess he deployed with different pods.

Comment: Now in my example I have 2 container in 1 pod. And I should replicate the pod. It's a first approach to understand k8s (in that case files in nginx folder will be replicated ). Obviously persistent volume between all the pods seems to be a better solution (I just try the conversion from docker compose with a simple empty volume). In any case I want to initialize the volume. Suggestion about this initialization?Is it possible to initialize a persistent volume?

Comment: As I said, you do that with an initContainer that also mounts the PV and sets up whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes doesn't have the Docker feature that copies content into volumes when the container is first started.

The two straightforward answers to this are:

1. Build a custom Nginx image that contains the static assets.  You can use the Dockerfile `COPY --from=other/image:tag` construct to copy them from your application container into the proxy container.
2. Store the assets somewhere outside container space altogether.  If you're deploying this to AWS, you can publish them to S3, and even directly serve them from a public S3 bucket.  Or if you have something like an NFS mount accessible to your cluster, have your overall build process copy the static assets there.

The Docker feature has many corner cases that are frequently ignored, most notably that content is only copied when the container is *first* started.  If you're expecting the volume to contain static assets connected to your application, and you update the application container, the named volume will not update.  As such you need some other solution to manage the shared content anyways, and I wouldn't rely on that Docker feature as a solution to this problem.

In Kubernetes you have the additional problem that you typically will want to scale HTTP proxies and application backends separately, which means putting them in different Deployments.  Once you have three copies of your application, which one provides "the" static assets?  You need to use something like a persistent volume to share contents, but most of the persistent volume types that are easy to get access to don't support multiple mounts.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify. So you suggest to create a persistent volume and share it with all the pods, is it possible and in this case how to initialize the persistent volume with data? As I said with docker compose is very easy.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a persistent volume over the two options above.  You would have to write code to populate and update it yourself (as @coderanger suggests, often with an initContainer, or with logic in the image's entrypoint script).